# Condição(if) não funciona para inserir dados

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Fiz essa query para inserir dados. Eu devo somente inserir dados, se não houver nada na tabela OIT1980. Aí montei um cursor e percorri e coloquei um IF. Se eu retirar o IF, funciona, mas se deixá-lo lá não, não sei se a forma como comparo está correta, mas veja o código abaixo:

```
set nocount on
declare 
@id_novo_rea int,
@id_exm_rea int,
@id_oit int, 
@i int

declare exame_cur cursor
 for
 select distinct er.id_exm_rea from t_cmo_Exame_Realizado er 
 inner join t_cmo_planilha_leitura pl on er.ID_XFC = pl.ID_XFC
 inner join t_cmo_exame ex on er.id_exm = ex.ID_EXM
 where er.id_exm = 3936 and pl.NO_EXM = 'TÓRAX: P.A.' and er.NO_RX in(select pl.RX_NUM from t_cmo_planilha_leitura pl)
 order by er.id_exm_rea

 open exame_cur
 fetch next from exame_cur into @id_exm_rea

 set @id_oit = (select max(id_oit) as id_oit from t_cmo_oit1980)

 while @@fetch_status = 0
 begin
    set @id_oit = @id_oit + 1

    set @id_novo_rea = (select distinct oit.id_exm_rea from t_cmo_planilha_leitura pl
    inner join t_cmo_Exame_Realizado er on pl.ID_XFC = er.ID_XFC and pl.RX_NUM = er.NO_RX
    inner join t_cmo_oit1980 oit on er.ID_EXM_REA = oit.ID_EXM_REA
    inner join t_cmo_exame ex on er.ID_EXM = ex.ID_EXM
    inner join t_cmo_oit1980_leitura  ol on oit.ID_OIT = ol.ID_OIT
    where er.ID_EXM_REA = @id_exm_rea)

    if @id_novo_rea = 0
    begin
        insert into t_cmo_oit1980_temp1 values
        (@id_oit,
         @id_exm_rea)
    end
    fetch next from exame_cur into @id_exm_rea
 end

 CLOSE exame_cur
 DEALLOCATE exame_cur
```

O resultado do select é zero(0)
A idéia é popular, com registros novos e não com existentes

Comment: Só vem uma linha nessa query? Chegou a tentar um `SELECT @id_novo_rea = oit.id_exm_rea ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Mudei e resolveu. Fiz assim:

```
set nocount on
declare 
@id_novo_rea int,
@id_exm_rea int,
@id_oit int, 
@i int

declare exame_cur cursor
 for
 select distinct er.id_exm_rea from t_cmo_Exame_Realizado er 
 inner join t_cmo_planilha_leitura pl on er.ID_XFC = pl.ID_XFC
 inner join t_cmo_exame ex on er.id_exm = ex.ID_EXM
 where er.id_exm = 3936 and pl.NO_EXM = 'TÓRAX: P.A.' and er.NO_RX in(select pl.RX_NUM from t_cmo_planilha_leitura pl)
 order by er.id_exm_rea

 open exame_cur
 fetch next from exame_cur into @id_exm_rea

 set @id_oit = (select max(id_oit) as id_oit from t_cmo_oit1980)

 while @@fetch_status = 0
 begin
    set @id_oit = @id_oit + 1

    if @id_exm_rea not in(select distinct oit.id_exm_rea from t_cmo_planilha_leitura pl
    inner join t_cmo_Exame_Realizado er on pl.ID_XFC = er.ID_XFC and pl.RX_NUM = er.NO_RX
    inner join t_cmo_oit1980 oit on er.ID_EXM_REA = oit.ID_EXM_REA
    inner join t_cmo_exame ex on er.ID_EXM = ex.ID_EXM
    inner join t_cmo_oit1980_leitura  ol on oit.ID_OIT = ol.ID_OIT)
    begin
        insert into t_cmo_oit1980_temp1 values
        (@id_oit,
         @id_exm_rea)
    end
    fetch next from exame_cur into @id_exm_rea
 end

 CLOSE exame_cur
 DEALLOCATE exame_cur
```